# Included function hides overloaded virtual functions

Tags: c++, class, function, virtual, overloading

I am developing a system using OpenCV.  This system has a class with a virtual function which has the same name (train) as a virtual function used by OpenCV.  When I compile, I get the following warning:

> /opt/local/include/opencv2/ml/ml.hpp:957:18: warning:
>   'CvForestTree::train' hides overloaded virtual functions
>   [-Woverloaded-virtual]

Most questions related to hiding overloaded virtual functions deal with classes and derived classes, but in this case my (perhaps incorrect) assumption the problem is that a class OpenCV implements has a function with the same name.  Note that OpenCV headers must be included for my class definition of the function to work.

Obviously, I'd prefer not to change the name of the function in the class I made and I suspect I am doing something stupid to get this problem.

EDIT: CvForestTree is OpenCV's class, not mine.  I'm not sure the exact area of line of code that causes the problem because the warning occurs for any file that includes OpenCV headers.  Maybe that means it is an OpenCV bug.

Comment: Is `CvForestTree` your own class or one from OpenCV?

Comment: Also, can you post a small code snippet that reproduces the problem. (See [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org))

Comment: This warning can only be produced if a subclass hides a function of its base. Unrelated classes cannot interact this way.

Comment: I'm having the same warning and none of my classes have a function called train... I'm using OpenCV 2.4.8. How did you get this warning fixed @sklum ?

Comment: @RafaelOliveira - I'm sorry, but I've entirely migrated my codebase away from the code for which this was a problem and I'm can't exactly remember how I got around it.  Of course, you could just turn off this particular type of compiler warning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem isn't with your code but the code of OpenCV: the `CvForestTree` class derives from `CvTree` and both classes have [virtual] `train()` member functions. Since the `CvForestTree` doesn't override all three overloads (I don't know if it overrides any but there are two `train()` overloads in `CvForestTree` and three in `CvTree`), at least one of the `CvTree::train()` functions is hidden.

The fix to the problem is to have a declaration like

```
using CvTree::train;
```

in the definition of `CvForestTree`. Of course, this isn't your class. That's one of the problems with warnings: The are often emitted for code you don't control.

Comment: So the fact that I have a class with the same function name is a coincidence or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: @scotwheels: Yes, I think that's right - unless, of course, you end up inheriting from the class. You can try it out: just include the header for `CvForestTree` and see if still yields the same warning.

Comment: It still yields the same warning but I'm not exactly clear on what you are getting at.  Since it still gets the same warning with only the CvForestTree header... then there is no way it is inheriting from the CvTree class because it has no knowledge of the CvTree class?

Comment: `CvForestTree` derives from `CvTree` according to [some documentation](http://groups.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/sdp/sdp1/OpenCV/share/opencv/doc/html/html/classCvForestTree.html). There are three overloads called `train()` in `CvTree` and two overloads in `CvForestTree`. That is, the declarations of `train()` in `CvForestTree` hide, at least, one of the three overloads in `CvTree`.

Comment: using CvDTree::train; should be used instead of using CvTree::train; within ml.hpp

Answer (score 0):

In fact you have to add this using CvDTree::train; in couple of places in ml.hpp:

```
class CV_EXPORTS CvBoostTree: public CvDTree
{
public:
  using CvDTree::train;
    CvBoostTree();


class CV_EXPORTS CvForestTree: public CvDTree
{
public:
  using CvDTree::train;
    CvForestTree();
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to add `using CvDTree::train;` in two lines within `include/opencv2/ml/ml.hpp`. 1.Within CvForestTree class definition:

```
class CV_EXPORTS CvForestTree: public CvDTree
{
using CvDTree::train;
```

2. Within CvBoostTree class definition:

```
class CV_EXPORTS CvBoostTree: public CvDTree
{
using CvDTree::train;
```